# Animating SVG path on hover with jQuery and Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, raphael

I'm trying to animate a segment of a path in Raphael when an element (`a#blog`) is hovered. I've been able to get the animated change to run on load with this JS and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8hbe/6/):

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 150, 150)
var pth = paper.path("M0 36L0 46L10 46" ).animate({path: "M0 16L0 46L10 46" }, 2000);
pth.attr({stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": "2"});
```

**But when I try to bind the event to .hover() with jQuery, it won't run**. Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong? Here's that JS and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5phQ/1/):

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 150, 150)
var pth = paper.path("M0 36L0 46L10 46" );
pth.attr({stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": "2"});

$("#blog").hover(function () {
    pth.animate({path: "M0 16L0 46L10 46" }, 2000);
}, function() {
    pth.animate({path: "M0 36L0 46L10 46" }, 2000);
});
```

I've found the Raphael docs a little tough to interpret, so if anyone out there has input it's appreciated!

Comment: This question was related to a similar problem (and question) I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22114705/1592764). The accepted answer on that question demonstrates the syntax for animating a path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating path coordinate changes in Raphael](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105403/animating-path-coordinate-changes-in-raphael)